# How to include build directory as source directory in intellij when compiling with gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build

By default, the gradle idea plugin marks the build folder as excluded. How do I include this folder as source folder? (or avoid excluding it, as it appears to be by default...)

In my module build.gradle file I tried with the two following configurations:

```
idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs -= file('build/generated')
    }
}
```

and:

```
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('build/generated')
    }
}
```

With those two configurations the folder build/generated always appears as excluded folders in IntelliJ after compilation.
In IntelliJ I always have to go in "Project Settings", "Modules" and then in the tab "Sources" to remove the build folder from the excluded folders and let my project run.

Comment: For people using the built in gradle import functionality in IDEA (i.e. not the gradle plugin) - go vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104847

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change code from

```
file('build/generated')
```

to

```
file("$buildDir/generated")
```

I use here is a working code:

```
ext {
    cxfOutputDir = file("$buildDir/generated-sources/cxf")
}
idea.module {
    excludeDirs -= file("$buildDir")
    sourceDirs += cxfOutputDir
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You definitely want the `build` directory to be excluded in IntelliJ. Otherwise, indexing will take longer, you'll get duplicates in searches, etc. Since IntelliJ doesn't support including a subdirectory of an excluded directory, my preferred solution is to put generated files into a directory outside `build`. For example, you could put them into `generated` (relative to the project directory), and configure the `clean` task accordingly:

```
clean {
    delete "generated"
}
```

Another option is to exclude all subdirectories of `build` except `build/generated`. However, given that the directories to be excluded will need be listed explicitly, this takes more effort, and bears the risk of being fragile. (You don't want this to break every time a plugin/task/etc. adds a new subdirectory.)

Comment: So I guess I cannot fight with IntelliJ and will just have to mark the required directory by hand after each build.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have control on that other module, it's coded by colleague and will take a while before any change. Excluding sub-directories leave the main directory build as excluded ans so doesn't help in getting the directory I need as source root. The only solution for now is to remove build directory from the excluded one and mark the generated as source root after the build (gradle cleanIdea idea delete this configuration so I have to do it after each build. Gradle module for Intellij being too slow for our big project I have no other choice). Anyway thank you for your time :-)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me!

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs -= buildDir
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works and is what the Q is looking for, but it is worth noting that it will now include everything from the build directory, not just generated code and that's undesirable (duplicates, longer time to index etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Use standard location for generated source code - supported without additional configuration:

```
${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/something
```

or

```
${project.buildDir}/generated-test-sources/something
```

for generated code for tests only.

`something` means technology, example: *jpamodel*, *cxf* etc.

Answer (score 0):

First method

```
['integration/src/generated'].each {
            idea.module.sourceDirs += file(it)
            sourceSets.main.java.srcDir it
            compileJava.source file(it)
    }
```

second method

```
project.ext {
        jaxbTargetDir = file("src/generated/java")
}

idea.module {
        excludeDirs -= file("$buildDir")
        sourceDirs += jaxbTargetDir
}
```