# When is gradle idea plugin useful?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, gradle

I've been trying to get IntelliJ to recognize some generated source unsuccessfully. See other question: 
[How to include build directory as source directory in intellij when compiling with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002517/how-to-include-build-directory-as-source-directory-in-intellij-when-compiling-wi)

Since the above isn't working, I'm asking this follow-up question.

It isn't clear from the documentation exactly when the idea plug-in is used. Is it only when you are initially setting the project up or does it also work afterwards, while you are using IntelliJ?